# can't connect to WSL2 after after executing wsl several times

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

## Environment

Windows10 home
▼WSL info

```
//Powershell
> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         2
```

▼.wslconfing setting
set .wslconfig file on C:\Users\ {username}

```
[wsl2]
memory=8GB
localhostForwarding=true
```

## Problem

▼ at first after running docker in WSL

```
・
・
・
web_1            | => Booting Puma
web_1            | => Rails 6.0.3 application starting in development
web_1            | => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
web_1            | [Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
web_1            | Puma starting in single mode...
web_1            | * Puma version: 5.1.1 (ruby 2.7.2-p137) ("At Your Service")
web_1            | *  Min threads: 5
web_1            | *  Max threads: 5
web_1            | *  Environment: development
web_1            | *          PID: 50
web_1            | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
web_1            | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

・When I try to connect from browser "localhost:3000", timeout error
・Serch "hostname -I" in WSL, and connect from browser of this IP address, connected

▼ after executing server several times
・Can't connect "localhsot", and even IP address which is serched by "hostname -I" as well (timeout error)

## Other

When I execute `curl http://localhost:3000` in Powershell, I get error

```
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest]、WebExce
    ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

The question was some time ago but one workaround currently is to shutdown WSL via

`wsl --shutdown`

You can then open up your distro and starting your server as usual.
Voilá you should be able to connect now.

If you are using Docker make sure to close it, if it is configured to use the WSL 2 backend. After your distro is up and running again you can launch Docker as usual.

Some issues on GH you could also relate to:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+connecting+localhost

**EDIT:**

make sure you have the latest WSL2 Kernel installed. Some issues are related to older Kernel versions. Current is 5.4.+

to get the Kernel updates automatically:

it is served by windows update if you check "include updates for other microsoft products"